# Why are the trash values printed?

Tags: c

My code is...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char department;
    double key;
    int i=0;
    while( (scanf("%c", &name[i])) == 1 ){
        i++;
    }
    name[i] = '\0';

    scanf("%d", &age);
    scanf("%c",&department);
    scanf("%lf",&key);


    puts(name);
    printf ("%d\n",age);
    printf("%c\n",department);
    printf("%g",key);

    return 0;
}
```

and input value is

```
mark
20
A
3.154
```

The result output should be same as input

```
mark
20
A
3.154
```

but what i got is ...

```
mark
20
A
3.154

32766
�
```

I wonder where

```
32766
�
```

comes from...

Comment: Your first loop with `while (scanf("%c", &name[i]) == 1)` should read all of standard input, quite probably overflowing the `name` array.  The `scanf()` calls afterwards should fail — you should be checking the return value from each of those.  That you get the input reprinted is because you first print `name`; the rest then is from the uninitialized (or overwritten) variables.  It might be easier to see if you used `printf("[[%s]]\n", name);` instead of `puts(name);` — you'd see the square brackets around all your input.

Comment: this is the key to your problem: `while( (scanf("%c", &name[i])) == 1 ){
        i++;
    }`   Suggest: `scanf( "%*s", sizeof(name)-1,  name);`  the =1 because '%s' and '%[...]' always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any chance of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d", &age);
    scanf("%c",&department);`  The input of `age` will leave the trailing newline in `stdin`.  however, the input format specifier `%c` does not consume leading 'white space' (like the newline) so `department` will contain something like '\n'.  then the input of `key` will fail.  Suggest: `scanf("%d", &age);
    scanf(" %c",&department);`   Notice the space before `%c`  That space will consume any leading white space.  The `scanf()` family of functions has a lot of details.  Suggest reading the MAN page until you fully understand those details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop with `while (scanf("%c", &name[i]) == 1)` should read all of standard input, quite probably overflowing the `name` array.  The `scanf()` calls afterwards should fail — you should be checking the return value from each of those.  That you get the input reprinted is because you first print `name`; the rest then is from the uninitialized (or overwritten) variables.  It might be easier to see if you used `printf("[[%s]]\n", name);` instead of `puts(name);` — you'd see the square brackets around all your input.

You could fix it by adding:

```
if (name[i] == '\n')
    break;
```

inside that initial while loop.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
while( (scanf("%c", &name[i])) == 1 ){
    i++;
}
```

will read *all* characters that it can, it will *not* stop at the end of `mark`.

Hence, the entire four lines are being read by that loop into `name`, then the `scan` calls *following* that are failing because there's no more input, meaning that the `age`, `department` and `key` values are left at whatever arbitrary value they had when they were created.

In other words, your output can be explained thusly:

```
mark  \
20     \
A       >-- name
3.154  /
      /
32766    -- age (and probably nul for department)
�       -- key
```

If you want to do line-based input, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf/2430310#2430310) provides a handy function for doing so, with buffer overflow protection and so on. For the strings, you just use them as entered, while the non-strings can be converted using `sscanf` on the buffer.